# How can I create only one bundle js file when I am using create-react starter with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Initially, I am using the create-react-app which during build produces 2 JS files after build, one is the main and the other one is the chunk.

But what if I would like after build to create only one bundle JS file?
The create-react starter has already webpack and babel in it.

So what is the way to go? To add a configuration? To install webpack again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First option is to [eject](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts#npm-run-eject) the create-react-app and modify the webpack config manually. But ejecting is an irreversible action, and usually not recommended.

A better option is to use [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) tool. `react-app-rewired` allows to modify the webpack config without ejecting:

```
/* Create a file config-overrides.js */

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  //do stuff with the webpack config...
  return config;
}
```

Comment: Hm, I like CRA. But those cases, which I am currently also experiencing, drive me to not using CRA. A good setup is explained [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-set-up-deploy-your-react-app-from-scratch-using-webpack-and-babel-a669891033d4/).
And don't be afraid to eject, if you still want to use CRA.